# Add 7 days to date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have select date from datepicker like this

```
let lastDate = $(`#search_legs_${newNumber - 1}_date`)
   .datepicker()
   .data("datepicker").selectedDates[0];
```

And have this in the console:

> Fri Jun 15 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

I need to add 7 dates to it to show in another datepicker

I try to do it like this

```
const newDate = new Date(lastDate.getDate() +7);
console.log(newDate);
```

But I get this in the console :

> Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

Where is my trouble?

Comment: `newDate = new Date; newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 7)` ... done

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Date(lastDate);
a.setDate(a.getDate() + 7);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It works

Comment: That doesn't use the date from the datepicker, it uses today's date.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, you are right, I should pass lastDate also.